# Convert Objects from Query to other Class in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have following problem: I am using Spring + Hibernate and am currently trying to select an id + amount of its id and return a list with each id and its corresponding amount. Now the problem is, that apperently the converter has a problem as I get following exception :

> ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting
>   from type [java.lang.Long] to type [...entity.E_Amount]] with root
>   cause

E_Amount creates Obejects with an id and an amount. And My Query:

```
 @Query("select t.e.id, count(t.id) from...")
```

returns a perfectly fine result of a long and an integer e.g. {9,101}

I am simply not completely sure how to start tackling this converting problem. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try the result class strategy:

**1)** Create a new class ResultClass with constructor accepting your query results:

```
public class ResultClass{

    public ResultClass(Integer id, Long count){..}
}
```

**2)** Amend the query a bit:

```
@Query("select new com.mypackage.ResultClass(t.e.id, count(t.id)) from...")
public List<ResultClass> query(..);
```

Just make sure that constructor arguments are in the same order as column in the select statement.

Comment: So basically as in my case E_Amount ? I tried it with select new com.*...*.E_Amount(...)) and now I received an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Ok so my current problem is that I actually have a spring/hibernate builder class for that object and therefore cant have a standard constructor , i think ? I am new to spring + hibernate so this is kinda confusing me. Anyway , my Server is giving me DetailedSemanticException as it cant locate an appropriate constroctur on class E_Amount ...